# IBM Quest Market-Basket Synthetic Data Generator

Tags: visual-c++

I recently need IBM Quest Market-Basket Synthetic Data Generator for my study on association rule mining. I found the program source code at link  http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~cgiannel/assoc_gen.html. 
But I couldn't compile this code on visual studio 2008 (because I haven't linux on my system)
I need the version of this code for visual studio 2008. do anyone have this code or can anyone help me to fix compile error.
So thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can [download illimine](http://illimine.cs.uiuc.edu/) from the University of Illinois. This link is on Jiawei Han's Web Page. If you look into illimine folders, there is a Windows compiled version for all the dataset generators.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download it from here:

http://forum.ai-directory.com/read.php?5,33

This page also offers several sequential patern mining datasets.